# Tensorflow - Keras how to pass string to first layer and obtain string from last layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying simple model for prediction sha1 hashes of strings, which should take the dataset consisting of string:sha1_string.

Dataset is generated in code.

```
import hashlib
import random
import string
import csv

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import argmax
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import Input
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

chars = string.printable
random.seed(0)
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

def convert_to_onehot(data):
    integer_encoded = [char_to_int[char] for char in data]
    onehot_encoded = list()
    for value in integer_encoded:
        letter = [0 for _ in range(len(chars))]
        letter[value] = 1
        onehot_encoded.append(letter)
    onehot_encoded = np.array(onehot_encoded)
    return onehot_encoded

def convert_from_onehot(data):
    inverted = "".join([int_to_char[argmax(value)] for value in data])
    return inverted

def create_dataset():
    dataset_file = open("dataset.csv", "w")
    dataset_writer = csv.writer(dataset_file, delimiter=":")
    for i in range(10000):
        str = []
        for x in range(64):
            str.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
        str = ''.join(str)
        hash = hashlib.sha1(str.encode()).hexdigest()
        dataset_writer.writerow([str, hash])
    dataset_file.close()

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    reg = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)
    model.add(Dense(160, input_shape=(len(chars),), kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(640, kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(320, kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(160, kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(len(chars), kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg, activation='sigmoid'))
    #opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['Accuracy', 'Precision'])
    return model

#create_dataset()
df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", sep=":", header=None)
dataset = df.values
train = dataset[:,0]
test = dataset[:,1]

for i, data in enumerate(train):
    train[i] = convert_to_onehot(data)
for i, data in enumerate(test):
    test[i] = convert_to_onehot(data)

#train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train)
#test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test)

model = create_model()
#model.summary()
model.fit(train, test, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2, epochs=100)
```

I find solution with one hot strings encodings, but code fails with "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor".

How to pass one hot arrays to tensors?

Comment: You can convert strings (char array) to floats and back.

Comment: How I can do it.

Comment: string -> char array -> ord() values in char_array -> np.array(char_array, dtype=np.float32) -> chr() values in char_array -> append all elements of char_array into new string

Comment: You won't be able to do that with `sigmoid` though, that's for binary classification. In your code, your output tensor will consist of 160 elements per prediction, with each element having a binary value for classification. If you want to try to work with floats that can be converted back to strings, it would probably be a regression problem, not classification, unless each element can be a representation of a letter?